# SQL How to update 2 columns second column based on the first column new value

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to access to the new value of the first updated column to use it in the second column in the same query update.

Assuming I have this update query:

```
UPDATE USER 
SET FIRST_NAME = (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM ANOTHER_TABLE) ,
    LAST_NAME = CASE 
                   WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'TOTO' FIRST_NAME 
                   ELSE FIRS_NAME || 'TITI' 
                END;
```

In this case if I use column 1 in column 2, I get the old value of column 1 not the new value.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following update statement:

```
update user
   set (first_name, last_name) =
(select first_name,
        decode(first_name, 'TOTO', first_name, first_name || 'TITI')
   from another_table);
```

Comment: It's a bit problematic because it works only if the another_table has exactly one row.

Comment: Nice idea i will try it i think it will work, yes the i retrieve only one row from another_table if i do the right where clause

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's behavior is correct.  Think of an `update` as having a *new* and an *old* version of each row.  The *new* version is on the left of the `set`.  The *old* version is on the right.

Oracle gives you several ways to address this.  One is by assigning both columns at the same time:

```
UPDATE USER
    SET (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME) =
            (SELECT FIRST_NAME,
                    (CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'TOTO' THEN FIRST_NAME ELSE FIRST_NAME || 'TITI' END)
             FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
            );
```

You can also update using an updatable subquery:

```
UPDATE (SELECT u.*,
               (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM ANOTHER_TABLE) as ANOTHER_FIRST_NAME
        FROM USER u
       ) 
    SET FIRST_NAME = ANOTHER_FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME = (CASE WHEN ANOTHER_FIRST_NAME = 'TOTO' THEN ANOTHER_FIRST_NAME ELSE FIRST_NAME || 'TITI' END);
```

Another method is to make `LAST_NAME` a computed column, so it does not need to be assigned explicitly.  And yet another method would use `MERGE` instead of `UPDATE`.